# Perfect Dark multiplayer ranks

Tags: perfect-dark

So Perfect Dark was an awesome game. But does anyone know/remember what all the ranks were?
What about all the other statistics as well...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IGN has a [guide](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/530/530017p1.html) that has exactly what you're looking for. The ranks are below:

> 1. Perfect
> 2. Near Perfect
> 3. Invincible
> 4. Elite
> 5. Lethal
> 6. Assassin
> 7. Killer
> 8. Deadly
> 9. Dangerous
> 10. Professional
> 11. Veteran
> 12. Expert
> 13. Special Agent
> 14. Star Agent
> 15. Agent
> 16. Trooper
> 17. Novice
> 18. Rookie
> 19. Amateur
> 20. Trainee
> 21. Beginner

The stats required to achieve Perfect are as follows:

> - Kills:  18,000
> - Damage Dealt:     180,000
> - Ammo Used:    450,000
> - Distance:     9000 km
> - Time:     12:12:00 (12 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes)
> - Games Won:    900
> - Accuracy Medals:  900
> - Head Shot Medals:     900
> - Killmaster Medals:    900
> - Survivor Medals:  900

If you also want a list of the messages you get after a match (like "Mostly Harmless"), I'm not sure if there's a compiled list readily available.