# How to rank up in perfect dark

Tags: perfect-dark

In the combat simulator in Perfect Dark N64, how do you rank up from rank 21 to rank 1?

Comment: From rank 21 to 1? It resets/goes down?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24868/perfect-dark-multiplayer-ranks?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated more about this question. It seems you start at rank 21 and go down to 1.  Seems backwards in today's video game industry.

Since you asked how to get to level 1 (Perfection rank), here are the requirements I found on [another website](http://m.ign.com/faqs/2004/perfect-dark-combat-simulator-rank-faq-530017):

- Kills:    18,000
- Damage Dealt: 180,000
- Ammo Used:    450,000
- Distance: 9000 km
- Time: 12:12:00 (12 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes)
- Games Won: 900
- Accuracy Medals:  900
- Head Shot Medals: 900
- Killmaster Medals:    900
- Survivor Medals: 900

Goodluck! Seems like it will take a while.

Comment: It's a rank, not a level. Levels go up, ranks go down.

Comment: I guess so. Depends on what you call a level or a rank. Take a call of Duty multiplayer rank for example. Those go up, but do you call them levels or ranks? Personally I say rank. But it's interchangeable